# Proof of provenance

Tags: authentication

Say Alice produces a bit of intellectual property, let's call it X. Alice is all for the freedom of information, so publishes X, without charge, electronically (e.g., on her website), asserting her copyright.

Bob comes along and finds X. He is so captivated by the content of which, he is moved to jealousy: He republishes X verbatim, again freely, but instead asserts his own copyright, without any mention of Alice. Let's call this X' (i.e., X' is Bob's plagiarism of X).

Charlie is interested in the topics discussed in X (and X') and, during a routine search, she comes across X'. Let's say Charlie is a "good actor" and performs due diligence and, for whatever reason, fails to uncover X. Charlie is satisfied and cites Bob and X' in his own published IP, Y.

Y becomes well known and Alice is made aware of it. Through this, she is shocked to discover X'. How can she prove herself to be the rightful copyright holder?

---

Let's assume, for the sake of this question, there are no metadata or artefacts (logs, drafts, version control, etc.) associated with the creation of X', that could be used to corroborate Alice's story. Moreover, any of the following could also be true:

- Bob has predated his copyright, relative to Alice.
- Bob has perfectly fabricated evidence of the creation of X' by himself.
- Alice independently verified the publication of X, but the verification service is not all-encompassing (i.e., it can't guarantee that X' wasn't created first, even if X was verified at a particular date).

Comment: As you have pretty much ruled out every last resort Alice could have had... sucks to be Alice.

Comment: Did Alice use a [timestamping service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) on X to make sure there was a record of when she uploaded it?

Comment: @user That’s what I meant by the last condition. I don’t see how this can verify that her work was done before Bob’s, unless one could some how mandate that all work be timestamped by a third party.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Haha :) Fair enough... Maybe a better question would be: “What could Alice have done differently to discredit Bob’s plagiarism?”

Comment: @Xophmeister By that logic nobody can verify anything. The burden of proof is on Bob to prove otherwise if Alice has some evidence that she created the work before him.

Comment: In academic world the work is typically kept secret until officially published. The digital world has blockchains. These are the technical tools Alice *had* before making the mistake of being rather naive. Anything above that might be more legal than information security issues.

Comment: The internet archive might be able to help (archive.org), if the data was published on Alice's website and it was indexed by the internet archive (they have cached copies of some pages and show the date when they were indexed). Some search engines might help too, or maybe even the hosting provider (caches, backups, timestamps, logs, etc.)